# Blur background for ProgressDialog android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, progressdialog, blur

Is there any way to blur or hide background when my `ProgressDialog` is showing.

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);


progressDialog.setMessage("Loding Data..");
progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
progressDialog.show();

//blur or hide my background screen

 progressDialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: I don't know how to do exactly what you are asking but I just thought work around trick. Just have  a image view which covers whole layout and make it invisible. Make it visible when progress starts and make it disable when progress bar stops. You can any blur image you want.  Let me know if you try this.

Comment: @AnkitMishra Good Idea ,I will try .Thank you. I will Let you know soon

Comment: You can rely on RenderScript